# Add extended class to ArrayList

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I want to add an object of class Special (which extends Mundane) to an ArrayList by using the add function.

What I have tried:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Mundane>> all = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Mundane>>();
all.add(Arrays.asList(
  specialThingy = new Special()
));
```

This gives me folowing error:
The method add(Class) in the type ArrayList> is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is

```
ArrayList<Mundane> all = new ArrayList<Mundane>();
all.add(new Special());
```

The `Class` and the `Arrays.asList` and the `specialThingy` are all just confusing matters.

If you want to *store* the `Special`, then just write

```
ArrayList<Mundane> all = new ArrayList<Mundane>();
Special specialThingy = new Special();
all.add(specialThingy);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but I'm actually using Arrays.asList so I can add multiple at onces. Any tips on that?

Comment: Three options: Call `add` on each of the elements individually, call `all.addAll(Arrays.asList(element1, element2, ...))` (note `addAll` instead of `add`), or use `Collections.addAll(all, element1, element2, ...)`.

Comment: Actually, there's a fourth option which is a one-liner: `List<Mundane> all = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(element1, element2, elements3));`. Assuming you'd want to add the elements right when you're creating the list.